# Хотел создать самоповторяющийся файл, но не получилось PYTHON

Tags: python, время, ос, sys

**base.txt**

```
import sys, os, time

cwd = os.getcwd()

code_file = "base.txt"
code_file = os.path.join(cwd, code_file)

my_name = sys.argv[0]
doter_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'clone' + (str(int(my_name.replace('clone', '').replace('.py', '').replace(cwd+'\\', ''))+1)) + '.py')

with open(doter_name, 'w') as f:
    with open(code_file) as readfile:
        f.write(readfile.read())

    time.sleep(1)

    os.system('python '+doter_name)
```

**clone1.py**

```
import sys, os, time

cwd = os.getcwd()

code_file = "base.txt"
code_file = os.path.join(cwd, code_file)

my_name = sys.argv[0]
doter_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'clone' + (str(int(my_name.replace('clone', '').replace('.py', '').replace(cwd+'\\', ''))+1)) + '.py')

with open(doter_name, 'w') as f:
    with open(code_file) as readfile:
        f.write(readfile.read())

    time.sleep(1)

    os.system('python '+doter_name)
```

Я запускаю код, но почему-то файл, который создала программа не запускается (не создает clone3.py и тд)
Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Все из-за того, что в такой постановке буфер еще не записался на диск, а процесс записи будет произведет по закрытию.

```
import sys, os, time

cwd = os.getcwd()

code_file = "base.txt"
code_file = os.path.join(cwd, code_file)

my_name = sys.argv[0]
doter_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'clone' + (str(int(my_name.replace('clone', '').replace('.py', '').replace(cwd+'\\', ''))+1)) + '.py')

with open(doter_name, 'w') as f:
    with open(code_file) as readfile:
        f.write(readfile.read())

time.sleep(15)

os.system('python '+doter_name)
```

Либо нужно явно указать запись буфера в виде `f.flush()`:

```
with open(doter_name, 'w') as f:
    with open(code_file) as readfile:
        f.write(readfile.read())

    f.flush()
    time.sleep(15)

    os.system('python '+doter_name)
```

Comment: Ну есть же стандартные термины - "буфер записывается на диск", либо "буфер сбрасывается на диск", что за "отписывание" такое, откуда? ))

Comment: Поправил) Спасибо